# How do I resolve dataloss & error with TermDocumentMatrix() and DocumentTermMatrix(), respectively?

Tags: r, utf-8, emoji, tf-idf, tm

I have a Twitter data of 1000 samples. And trying to do some tf and tf-idf analysis on them to measure the importance of each emoticons in tweets. There are total of 437 unique emoticons, and 810 tweets.

My current problem is that with `TermDocumentMatrix`, all the terms are not showing. Whereas, with `DocumentTermMatrix` there is a error which I can't get around. Here is a working code snippet:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(tm)
library(tidyr) 

#These are NOT from the my data, these are random fake bios I found online just to make this code snippet
tweets_data <- c("Sharp, adversarial⚔️~pro choice~ban Pit Bulls☠️~BSL️~aberant psychology~common sense~the Piper will lead us to reason~sealskin woman",
                 "Blocked by Owen, Adonis. Abbott & many #FBPE Love seaside, historic houses & gardens, family & pets. RTs & likes/ Follows may=interest not agreement ",
                 " #healthy #vegetarian #beatchronicillness fix infrastructure",
                 "LIBERTY-IDENTITARIAN. My bio, photo at Site Info. And kindly add my site to your Daily Favorites bar. Thank you, Eric",
                 "I #BackTheBlue for my son! Facts Over Feelings. Border Security saves lives! #ThankYouICE",
                 " I play Pedal Steel @CooderGraw & #CharlieShafter #GoStars #LiberalismIsAMentalDisorder",
                 "#Englishman  #Londoner  @Chelseafc  ️‍♂️   ",
                 "F*** the Anti-White Agenda #Christian #Traditional #TradThot #TradGirl #European #MAGA #AltRight #Folk #Family #WhitePride",
                 "❄️Do not dwell in the past, do not dream of the future, concentrate the mind on the present moment.️❄️",
                 "Ordinary girl in a messed up World | Christian | Anti-War | Anti-Zionist | Pro-Life | Pro  | Hello intro on the Minds Link |")

emoticons_data <- c("","","","","")

TagSet <- data.frame(emoticons_data)
colnames(TagSet) <- "emoticon"

TextSet <- data.frame(tweets_data)
colnames(TextSet) <- "tweet"

myCorpus <- tm::Corpus(tm::VectorSource(TextSet$tweet))

tdm <- tm::TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus, control= list(stopwords=T))

tdm_onlytags <- tdm[rownames(tdm)%in%TagSet$emoticon, ]

tm::inspect(tdm_onlytags) #Only shows 1 terms, and not 5
#View(as.matrix(tdm_onlytags[1:tdm_onlytags$nrow, 1:tdm_onlytags$ncol])) #just to see in new window
```

[image]

Furthermore, if I try to do the tf-idf, I just get the error. I have looked around, but I don't know where I should fix my mistake.

```r
tdm <- tm::as.DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus, control= list(weighting= weightTfIdf))
tdm #Original= Error in dim(data) <- dim : dims [product 810] do not match the length of object [3]
```

[image]

It is my first time using `tm` package.

Comment: My tip: use `quanteda` instead of `tm`. When I was still using `tm` I kept running into crap like this constantly. `quanteda` is a modern and fast alternative which doesn't constantly run into weird encoding issues.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that "words" are only split at spaces. If you have an emoji next to a word with no spaces, it's considered to be just part of that word.

Comment: Thank you @JBGruber! Never heard of it, will check it out. Need a favour if you don't mind, could you show me a quick example using above data? It's not issue if you're busy :)

Comment: Thanks, @MrFlick, yes you're correct. I just put a Swedish and Black flag, and they show in terms now. Interesting, any thoughts to get around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I slightly changed your original data as your emoticons each only appear once in the text, which turns all values in tfidf to 1 (see below, I just randomly added a few ). I'm using `quanteda` instead of `tm` as it is faster and has far less problems with encoding.

```
library(dplyr)
library(quanteda)

tweets_dfm <- dfm(TextSet$tweet)  # convert to document-feature matrix

tweets_dfm %>% 
  dfm_select(TagSet$emoticon) %>% # only leave emoticons in the dfm
  dfm_tfidf() %>%                 # weight with tfidf
  convert("data.frame")           # turn into data.frame to display more easily
#>    document <U+0001F914> <U+0001F4AA> <U+0001F603> <U+0001F953> <U+0001F37A>
#> 1     text1      1.39794            1            0            0            0
#> 2     text2      0.00000            0            1            0            0
#> 3     text3      0.00000            0            0            0            0
#> 4     text4      0.00000            0            0            0            0
#> 5     text5      0.00000            0            0            0            0
#> 6     text6      0.69897            0            0            0            0
#> 7     text7      0.00000            0            0            1            1
#> 8     text8      0.00000            0            0            0            0
#> 9     text9      0.00000            0            0            0            0
#> 10   text10      0.00000            0            0            0            0
```

The column names (i.e., emojis) are displayed correctly in my Viewer and it should be possible to export the resulting data.frame.

#### data

```
TagSet <- data.frame(emoticon = c("","","","",""),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

TextSet <- data.frame(tweet = c("Sharp, adversarial⚔️~pro choice~ban Pit Bulls☠️~BSL️~aberant psychology~common sense~the Piper will lead us to reason~sealskin woman",
                                "Blocked by Owen, Adonis. Abbott & many #FBPE Love seaside, historic houses & gardens, family & pets. RTs & likes/ Follows may=interest not agreement ",
                                " #healthy #vegetarian #beatchronicillness fix infrastructure",
                                "LIBERTY-IDENTITARIAN. My bio, photo at Site Info. And kindly add my site to your Daily Favorites bar. Thank you, Eric",
                                "I #BackTheBlue for my son! Facts Over Feelings. Border Security saves lives! #ThankYouICE",
                                " I play Pedal Steel @CooderGraw & #CharlieShafter #GoStars #LiberalismIsAMentalDisorder",
                                "#Englishman  #Londoner  @Chelseafc  ️‍♂️   ",
                                "F*** the Anti-White Agenda #Christian #Traditional #TradThot #TradGirl #European #MAGA #AltRight #Folk #Family #WhitePride",
                                "❄️Do not dwell in the past, do not dream of the future, concentrate the mind on the present moment.️❄️",
                                "Ordinary girl in a messed up World | Christian | Anti-War | Anti-Zionist | Pro-Life | Pro  | Hello intro on the Minds Link |"),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks a million sir. I will transition from ```tm``` to ```quanteda``` ASAP. I am glad I met you right on time, I was going to invest more time in ```tm``` in the future. Have a blessed day!

Comment: @ToadPitt, you also might want to look into the package textclean. With it, you can replace (or remove) emojis and emoticons before continuing on with quanteda.

Comment: You're welcome! `tm` was great when peopl were starting to do text analysis in `R` and paved the way. But `quanteda` just works better nowadays.

Comment: @phiver Thank you! Yep, I am familiar with that package. I used that to do some prior analysis with network graphs and emojis extraction, however I didn't know how to go on using that with text-mining you know.

Comment: @JBGruber yeah, that's how it seems. I am reading some tutorial at quanteda[dot]io, and author is pointing out the limitations of ```tm``` package. I didn't know this package existed. Thanks for letting me know ;)

Comment: Sorry about the last comment. I needed a scope resolution operator in front to get rid of ```Error in UseMethod("convert") :....```. Because I had a custom function called "convert." I didn't have this package before. Good day sir!